# How to find the valid phone number length given a Country and PhoneType, using libphonenumber-js

Tags: javascript, libphonenumber

I'm using the `libphonenumber-js` library from **CDN `jsdelivr`**

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/libphonenumber-js/bundle/libphonenumber-js.min.js

Given I have a valid **`CountryCode`** (eg `AU`) and a **`PhoneType`** of `mobile` or `fixed line`, is there some way I can find the numeric **`length`** of a valid phone number for that type and country?